# WooCommerce: conditional handling fee that is not applied to only one coupon code

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, fee

I have implemented code that will charge a $1.50 handling fee to all WooCommerce products unless a coupon code is used. However, I only want the handling fee to be removed for a single coupon as opposed to when any coupon is used. Thoughts? Below is my current code and the only coupon that should not have the handling fee applied is QFPZ8KSS (the post ID for the coupon is 4432 if that is required).

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','conditional_handling_fee' );

function conditional_handling_fee() {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Get the applied coupons + the count (in cart)
    $applied_coupons_arr = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();
    $applied_coupons_count = count($applied_coupons_arr);

    $fee = 1.50;

    if( 0 == $applied_coupons_count )
        WC()->cart->add_fee( ''.$applied_coupons_count, $fee, true, 'standard' );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to compare the coupon used in your order against your free shipping one. I think the below should work, bear in mind I haven't tested this. Hopefully it will help.

```html
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','conditional_handling_fee' );

function conditional_handling_fee() {

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

// Get the applied coupons + the count (in cart)
$applied_coupons_arr = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();

$fee = 1.50;

  $applied_coupon_ids;

  // Coupons used in the order loop
  foreach( $applied_coupons_arr as $coupon ){

      // Get Coupon ID
      $coupon_post_obj = get_page_by_title($coupon, OBJECT, 'shop_coupon');
      $coupon_id       = $coupon_post_obj->ID;

      // Store in array
      array_push($applied_coupon_ids, $coupon_id);
  };
  
  // Check if your free shipping coupon is used
  if(! in_array('COUPON_ID_HERE', $applied_coupon_ids)){
    WC()->cart->add_fee( ''.$applied_coupons_count, $fee, true, 'standard' );
  };
?>
```

Comment: Hey there and thank you for the reply! When I add in your provided code (and replace COUPON_ID_HERE with 4432) it does not remove the $1.50 handling fee with the coupon code is applied. Perhaps "$fee = 0;" needs to be added in somewhere conditionally?

Comment: When I go in to edit the coupon the URL ends with "post=4432&action=edit" which suggests 4432 is the coupon ID. Is that correct?